# how export a variable in from fetch

Tags: javascript, export

I need to export my apiData variable to access it in another file. But I can't do it via export (synthaxe error) and I must not use local storage. So how to do it ?

```
fetch(apiUrl).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        } else {
            console.error('fail to connect to api');
        }
    }).then(responseData => {
        // remove loader 
        document.getElementById("load").style.display = 'none'
        let apiData = responseData;
        // put data in local storage
        // localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(apiData))
})
```

thanks

Comment: Export the promise, then work with the promise. But that might be a bad idea. You can also export the function that will do the `fetch()` call for you and call it when you need it.

Comment: "must not use localStorage" Why not?